# Make an ajax request from a Prestashop module

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I am making a module and I need to make an ajax request, with JSON response if possible, how can i do this ? 
I don't understand really well the structure of Prestashop 1.7 on this.

Thanks !

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is pretty simple, you just have to make the controller with Prestashop's standards then link it to your frontend Javascript.

Name a php file like this : ./modules/modulename/controllers/front/ajax.php

Then put inside :

```
<?php

// Edit name and class according to your files, keep camelcase for class name.
require_once _PS_MODULE_DIR_.'modulename/modulename.php';

class ModuleNameAjaxModuleFrontController extends ModuleFrontController
{
    public function initContent()
    {

        $module = new ModuleName;

        // You may should do some security work here, like checking an hash from your module
        if (Tools::isSubmit('action')) {

            // Usefull vars derivated from getContext
            $context = Context::getContext();
            $cart = $context->cart;
            $cookie = $context->cookie;
            $customer = $context->customer;
            $id_lang = $cookie->id_lang;

            // Default response with translation from the module
            $response = array('status' => false, "message" => $module->l('Nothing here.'));

            switch (Tools::getValue('action')) {

                case 'action_name':

                    // Edit default response and do some work here
                    $response = array('status' => true, "message" => $module->l('It works !'));
                    
                    break;

                default:
                    break;

            }
        }

        // Classic json response
        $json = Tools::jsonEncode($response);
        echo $json;
        die;

        // For displaying like any other use this method to assign and display your template placed in modules/modulename/views/template/front/...
        // Just put some vars in your template
        // $this->context->smarty->assign(array('var1'=>'value1'));
        // $this->setTemplate('template.tpl');

        // For sending a template in ajax use this method
        // $this->context->smarty->fetch('template.tpl');

    }
}

?>
```

In your Module Hooks, you need to bring access to the route in JS, so we basicaly make a variable :

```
// In your module PHP
public function hookFooter($params)
{
    
    // Create a link with the good path
    $link = new Link;
    $parameters = array("action" => "action_name");
    $ajax_link = $link->getModuleLink('modulename','controller', $parameters);

    Media::addJsDef(array(
        "ajax_link" => $ajax_link
    ));

}
```

On the frontend side, you just call it like this in a JS file (with jQuery here) :

```
// ajax_link has been set in hookfooter, this is the best way to do it
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.getJSON(ajax_link, {parameter1 : "value"}, function(data) {

        if(typeof data.status !== "undefined") {

            // Use your new datas here
            console.log(data);

        }

    });

});
```

And voila, you have your ajax ready to use controller

Comment: Die? Like really? Use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;

Comment: This was some time ago, it would be better to use native solution, but this one will reject the same answer. Using fondamental Symfony is not mandatory and therefore not backward compatible ...

Comment: Yes, I was googling a little after that and old PS really doesn't have any "best practice" solution... die is really messy...