# Ajax Request (Prestashop 1.7)

Tags: javascript, ajax, module, prestashop, product

I would like to manage to recover the product of the current page from the module so that I can make my request Ajax.
Is there something missing or did I do something wrong? I saw that in the request there was in the URL the product id when we add the product to the cart, is what we have to do to retrieve the id?
 [module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6aQrh.png)  [ajax](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fnrG3.png)  [javascript](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLUMS.png)

module side :

```
public function getProduct() {
    $id = $this->hookDisplayProductActions();
    $product = new Product($id);
    return $product;
}

public function hookDisplayProductActions() {
    return Tools::getValue('id_product');
}
```

ajax side :

```
class MultiTransporteursAjaxModuleFrontController extends 
ModuleFrontController
{
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}

public function init()
{
    parent::init();
}

public function initContent(){
    parent::initContent();
}
```

}

javascript side :

```
var mt_ajax = prestashop.urls.base_url + 
'modules/multitransporteurs/controllers/front/ajax';
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#carriers').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url:mt_ajax,
        data: {id_product:$(this).val()},
        method:'GET',
        success:function(data) {
            $('.ajax_carriers').html(data);
        },
    });
  });
})
```

Comment: [Please add your code as text (not images) to your question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) I also highly recommend reading [ask].

Comment: [No images of code please](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't call the hookdisplayProductActions method

```
public function getProduct() {
    $id = Tools::getValue('id_product');
    $product = new Product($id);
    return $product;
 }
```

You should assign id_product in controller side and put it in an input type hidden in your form
For ajax controller side you can try this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/43697852/16244750 don't forget to use die($res) for the json result
Don't forget to send 'action' parameter in ajax request

Answer (score 0):

It not so hard do it, you have to use the `action` attribute from Prestashop.

In java-script you send the data like this:

```
   $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        dataType : 'JSON',
        url: mt_ajax
        data: { action: 'myScript', myvariable:150},
        success: function(data) {
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log('Error: ' + textStatus + ' ' + errorThrown);
        }
    });
```

In PHP you fetch the results like this:

```
   public function ajaxProcessMyScript()
   {
        $myvar = (int)Tools::getValue('myvariable');
        if ($myvar) {
            echo Tools::jsonEncode('Message received!');
        } else {
            echo Tools::jsonEncode('Oops, something went wrong!');
        }
   }
```